# Update UIButton's image according to Model

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableView where each cell get's its data from my model class, which is an array in my TableViewController class. The model for each cell is set in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**. My model has a "isFavorited" property. My custom cell class has a UIButton with an image of a star.

If **model.isFavorited == false**, the UIButton image is a gray star.

If **model.sFavorited == true**, the UIButton image should change to a yellow star.

So far, I have tried to approach this like so:

```
private let normal = UIImage(named: "star")
private let selection = UIImage(named: "star highlighted")

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
      var model: Model? {
          didSet{
             favoriteButton.selected = (model?.isFavorite)!
          }
      }

      @IBOutlet var favoriteButton: UIButton!

      override func awakeFromNib() {
          super.awakeFromNib()
          favoriteButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = true
          favoriteButton.setImage(normal, forState: .Normal)
          favoriteButton.setImage(selection, forState: .Highlighted)
          favoriteButton.setImage(selection, forState: .Selected)
      }

      @IBAction func favoriteTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
          //UPDATE THE MODEL
          model?.isFavorite = !(model?.isFavorite)!
      }

}
```

This code successfully changes a star from gray to yellow and vice-versa thanks to didSet being called to update the `favoriteButton.selected` boolean with the value from `(model?.isFavorite)!`.

HOWEVER, as I scroll far enough through my tableview, and try to come back to the specific cell I favorited, the image will reappear as unfavorited (gray star instead of yellow star).

If my model is being updated when I tap the button, and the UIButton's image is adjusted during didSet as a result of this change, why does it revert back to the defaulted state when scrolling back to this cell??

EDIT:
My code in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.model = modelArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I know what's going on here. Can you post your code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so I can answer with code?

Comment: See my updated post for the code.

Comment: Yeah.. scratching my head now. Actually looks fine to me. First step though is to figure out where the problem is coming from. I would put a print statement in that didSet callback to print the model.isFavorite value. BTW, use `model!.isFavorite`, not `(model?.isFavorite)!`, the latter is contradicting

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could subclass the `UIButton` with custom images set based on the tap. I had the same issue and solved it using below:

```
class FavioriteButton: UIButton {
    //Images
    let normalImage = UIImage(named: "star")! as UIImage
    let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "star_highlighted")! as UIImage

    //Bool property
    var isSelected: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if isSelected == true {
                self.setImage(normalImage, forState: .Normal)
            }else{
                self.setImage(selectedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.isSelected = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == self {
            if isSelected == true {
                isSelected = false
            }else{
                isSelected = true
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This produces a different bug. Now when I scroll through the tableView, other cells that share the same reused cell have a highlighted star. Scrolling up and down will change the stars randomly.

Comment: You need to set the `isSelected` properly in your cell.